# How to make list better?

Tags: android, listview

I have this code but I am unable to find out how it is working specially get view method.
I am also unable to find out what is `public View` getView(int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent)

```
public class DynamicDemo extends ListActivity {
    TextView selection;
    String[] items={"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet",
    "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi", "vel",
    "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis",
    "etiam", "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante",
    "porttitor", "sodales", "pellentesque", "augue",
    "purus"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setListAdapter(new IconicAdapter(this));
    selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
    }
    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v,
    int position, long id) {
    selection.setText(items[position]);
    }
    class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    Activity context;
    IconicAdapter(Activity context) {
    super(context, R.layout.row, items);
    this.context=context;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
    ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);
    label.setText(items[position]);
    if (items[position].length()>4) {
    ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
    }
    return(row);
    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getView() method is called for each row of the ListView when it gets visibility Typically you inflate an xml, like you did in your code

> Explanation of the parameters :

```
int position
```

position in the adapter

```
View convertView
```

Used for recycling row items

```
ViewGroup parent
```

Parent viewgroup to which this view will be added to.